# Setting Back camera by default in NodeCameraView React Native

Tags: android, react-native, node-media-server

I tried to get the Live Stream to work using package named **react-native-nodemediaclient** in react native and got it to work.

Here We have our Front camera to open by default and we can able to switch the camera view. But, I want Back camera to be opened by default.

Here's the camera setting I used which opens front camera.

```
videoSettings = {
  preset: 12,
  bitrate: 400000,
  profile: 1,
  fps: 15,
  videoFrontMirror: false,
};

cameraSettings = {cameraId: 1, cameraFrontMirror: true};
```

I have modified the camera Id and cameraFrontMirror option but it didn't opened any camera (neither front nor back).

Searched google but didn't get anything to work.

Kindly let me know the settings to use back camera by default.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<NodeCameraView 
  style={{ width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT }}

  ref={(vb) => {
        setVbRef(vb);
            }}

 outputUrl={rtmpUrl}

 camera={{ 
   cameraId: 0, 
   cameraFrontMirror: false 
}}

audio={{
  bitrate: 32000,
  profile: 1, 
  samplerate: 44100 
}}

video={{
  preset: 12,
  bitrate: 400000,
  profile: 1,
  fps: 30,
  videoFrontMirror: false,
}}
 autopreview
    />
```

Comment: just add cameraId:0 and cameraFrontMirror: false in your cameraSettings

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will try and let you know for the result